# Remove embedly header

Tags: embedly

Is it possible to remove the header from Embedly cards? I want to remove or hide the entire div.hdr section, including both the provider-favicon and provider-name, so that only the div.bd body of the card displays.

Code I'm posting is:

```
<a class="embedly-card" data-card-key="3b4de9c48f78449989436d6d3adefda5" data-card-chrome="0" data-card-controls="0" data-card-via="0" href="http://www.domain.com/folder/filename.jpg"></a> <script async src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Code that renders is:

```
<div class="card image"><div class="hdr"><div class="provider provider-gt-35"><span class="provider-favicon"></span><a class="provider-name" target="_blank" href="http://www.MYURL.com">SITETITLE</a><span class="author">&nbsp;</span></div></div><div class="bd"><div class="pair-bd"><div class="art-bd"><a target="_blank" href="#"></a><a href="http://www.MYURL.com/sites/default/files/images/folder/test-450x100.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="art-bd-img" src="http://i-cdn.embed.ly/1/display?key=fd92ebbc52fc43fb98f69e50e7893c13&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MYURL.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fimages%2Ffolder%2Ftest-450x100.jpg" style="opacity: 1;"></a></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Code added above, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Embedly permits CSS customization for paid accounts based on the "embedly-css" class.

`<style class="embedly-css">
    .card .hdr {
        display:none;
    }
</style>`